ReactNative Android TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of null, js engine: hermes
I am trying to execute a simple API using fetch in Android (ReactNative), while I am a fresher after googling a lot I am finally putting it here. I am getting an error while executing my code. My question here is what is going wrong in the code please guide me.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of null, js engine: hermes

The source code :
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { fetch } from "react-native-ssl-pinning";

export default function App() {

const fetchUserData = () => {
  console.log("onClick Fetch data-------------->");
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", {
    method: "GET",
    timeoutInterval: 10000,
    sslPinning: {
      certs: ["mycert"],
    },
  })
   .then((response) => {
     console.log("in Response-------------->", response.data);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(response.bodyString, null, "\t"));
   })
   .catch((error: any) => {
     console.log("ERROR-------------->", error.header);
     console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    });
};

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>This is a Testing app for network error</Text>
    <Button title="Fetch User Data" onPress={fetchUserData} />
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
  </View>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  marginTop: "auto",
},
});

